# Type '{ name: string; } & Pick<TProps, Exclude<keyof TProps, "name">>' is not assignable to type 'TProps'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a [React HoC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that will set some props if they haven't been provided.

I can provide that code if needed, but it comes with some React baggage that complicates the code and doesn't actually have anything to do with the error I'm encountering.

So I've created an MVCE that reproduces the problem in a clearer way:

```
interface RequiredProps {
    name?: string;
}

const setDefaults = <TProps extends RequiredProps>(props: TProps) => {
    const {
        name: nameProp,
        ...rest
    } = props;

    const newProps: TProps = {
        name: (nameProp != null) ? nameProp : "Alice",
        ...rest
    };

    return newProps;
};
```

`props` is immutable, so if it comes in with `name` as `undefined` then I can't do:

```
if (props.name == null) {
    props.name = "alice";
}
```

and I get the error:

> [TypeError: Cannot add property XXX, object is not extensible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible)

So instead, I used [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to grab the fields I know should be there, and to put the rest in `...rest`.

Then I construct `newProps` combining the fields I'm defaulting, and the `...rest`.

The problem is that at that point I then get the error:

> Type `{ name: string; } & Pick<TProps, Exclude<keyof TProps, "name">>` is not assignable to type `TProps`.

To me that reads as "TProps, excluding the name property, plus the name field, cannot be assigned to TProps", which leaves me a bit confused.

I wondered if it didn't like that `name` was now `string` rather than `string?`. It didn't make sense that the problem would be that, since `string` is assignable to `string?`, but I tried modifying the code anyway.

```
const newProps: TProps = {
    name: ((nameProp != null) ? nameProp : "Alice") as string | undefined,
    ...rest
};
```

But as expected, that made no difference.

I noticed that in the error message it says the type is `{ name: string; }` rather than `{ name?: string; }`, so I made a code change to try and address that.

```
const newRequiredProps: { name?: string } = {
    name: (nameProp != null) ? nameProp : "Alice"
};

const newProps: TProps = {
    ...newRequiredProps,
    ...rest
};
```

The error message now showed a "more correct" type, but it remained fundamentally the same.

> Type `{ name?: string; } & Pick<TProps, Exclude<keyof TProps, "name">>` is not assignable to type `TProps`.

I did find one thing that worked, which was forcing the type using `as`:

```
const newProps: TProps = {
    name: (nameProp != null) ? nameProp : "Alice",
    ...rest
} as TProps;
```

But that feels like I'm just covering up the typing issue, and not actually solving it.

Is there a way to get the type system to understand what I'm trying to do, rather than forcing it to accept the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult for the compiler to verify complex conditional type manipulation on generic types.  The type assertion you're doing is perfectly acceptable as long as you are sure that nothing crazy is going to happen like this:

```
type PossiblyBob = { name?: "Bob" };
const possiblyBob: PossiblyBob = Math.random() < 0.5 ? {} : { name: "Bob" };
setDefaults(possiblyBob);
```

Note that the type `PossiblyBob` has a `name` property which must either be the string `"Bob"` or `undefined`.  And when you call `setDefaults(possiblyBob)` it instantiates `TProps` as `PossiblyBob`.  But that inside your `setDefaults()` implementation, `newProps` has a 50% chance of being `{name: "Alice"}` at runtime, which is *not* a `PossiblyBob`.  Oh well.

But assuming such edge cases are not going to happen, you can just tell the compiler not to worry and use a type assertion.

A possibly shorter way to say the same thing which doesn't require a type assertion is to use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const setDefaults: TProps = <TProps extends RequiredProps>(props: TProps) => {            
  const newProps = Object.assign({ name: "Alice" }, props);      
};
```

This is more or less the same thing (as long as `props.name` isn't actually *set* to be the value `undefined`).  The lack of type error is kind of a trick, though.  The [standard library typings](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L286) for `Object.assign()` returns the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of the types of its inputs, which is [not technically true](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11100).  Eventually they will probably [update](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) the return type of `Object.assign()` and then you'll have the same type assertion issue there too.

So I guess my suggestion is to leave the type assertion and carry on.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for having a look and the explanation.